# SOAPException Server temporarily unavailable

Tags: java, soap, client-server

What is this exception? I tried googling it but there is no related item. The service on startup tries to bind to a port and then communicate with the server on remote machine. It was working fine and suddenly it just popped up on all the Windows 7 64 bit machines that are running it.

Electric.util.WrappedExeption: SOAPException( Server: Service temporarily unavailable. )
 at electric.proxy.handler.Proxy.getCompatibleException(Unknown Source)
 at electric.proxy.handler.Proxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at $Proxy0.sendCommand(UnknownSource)

Comment: Have you found anything in the server log? Any exceptions while parsing SOAP envelope?

Comment: Nothing. This is the exception that is for the logs. This is the client side of the app and no server here